# Is it possible to turn off any autoparallelization with gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, parallel-processing, openmp

I am working on parallel algorithms using OpenMP. Judging from the CPU usage, much of the "sequential" code I write is actually executed in parallel.

For example:

```
#pragma omp parallel for if (par == "parallel")
for (int64_t u = 1; u <= n; ++u) {
    for (int64_t v = u + 1; v <= n; ++v) {
        ....
    }
}
```

This is conditionally parallel if a flag is set. With the flag set, I see CPU usages of 1500% on a 16 core machine. With the flag not set, I still see 250% CPU usage.

I suppose this is due to some autoparallelization going on. Correct? Does GCC do this?

Since I need to compare sequential and parallel running times, I would like code not annotated with (`#pragma omp parallel...` etc.) to run on one CPU only. Can I achieve this easily? Is there a GCC flag by which I can switch of autoparallelization and have parallelism where I explicitly annotate with OpenMP?

Comment: I am not aware of gcc magically parallelizing anything you don't tell it explicitly per default...

Comment: @PlasmaHH I tell it to optimize with `-O3`. Am I telling it to autoparallelize anywhere?

Comment: @cls: I'm pretty sure gcc doesn't do any kind of implicit automagical parallelization (as in it can't).

Comment: Okay, this is also an answer. Any idea where these CPU usage figures come from?

Comment: Unless you've explicitly enabled the automatic loop parallelisation with `-ftree-parallelize-loops=<nthreads>`, you should use a debugger or a threads checker tool (these usually provide nice graphs of threads activity) in order to investigate where the other 150% CPU usage come from. (Btw, how do you get 15000% CPU usage on a machine with 16 cores?)

Comment: @HristoIliev I meant 1500%

Comment: Do you link to any threaded libraries?

Comment: @Thomas Yes. How does that influence my sequential loop?

Comment: @cls I once had a similar effect where a non-threaded program was starting many threads.  We traced it back to the boehm garbage collection to which we linked.  Our test code created many objects that were subsequently garbage collected and the gc library was threaded.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the OpenMP `if` clause exerts *run-time rather than compile-time* control over the concurrency. It means that while the condition inside the `if` clause might evaluate to false when the program is executed, which deactivates the `parallel` region by setting the number of threads in its team to 1, the region would still expand to several runtime calls and a separate function for its body, although this would not lead to parallel execution. The OpenMP runtime might also keep a running pool of OpenMP threads busy-waiting for tasks.

The only way to guarantee that your OpenMP code would compile as a clearly serial executable (given that you do not link to parallel libraries) is to compile with OpenMP support disabled. In your case that would mean no `-fopenmp` option given to GCC while the code is being compiled.

Comment: Very informative. Do you think the CPU usage of about 200% is due to the OpenMP runtime using that many cycles?